# Could not insert complete values into database using stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I'm very new to using stored procedure in C#. But m unable to insert the values into database completely?

```
create procedure insertPro
     (@name as varchar,
      @lname as varchar,
      @phone as varchar)
as
    insert into std_info 
    values (@name, @lname, @phone)
go
```

And here is my C# code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=xxxxx");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertPro",con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

This insert values into database but not completely for example, if i insert first name as abc then it only insert a and same for the last name and phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your stored procedure to:

```
create procedure insertPro
(
   @name as varchar(max), //change (max) to maximum constraint length you set for each column
   @lname as varchar(max),
   @phone as varchar(max)
) 
as 

  insert into std_info values (@name,@lname,@phone)
```

Comment: Would qualify this by saying the table should correspond to the definition in the procedure (i.e. varchar(max), otherwise SQL Server will throw a truncation exception

Comment: Yes, that is why I added comment to change it to proper length :)

Answer (score 3):

Put a length on your parameters:

```
create procedure insertPro(
@name as varchar(30),
@lname as varchar(30),
@phone as varchar(30)
```

Comment: Note that you must change the length to the actual column length of your table.

Answer (score 1):

```
@name as varchar
```

So using simple `varchar` without any length specified. It takes only single character. So that's why you are seeing only one character in your table. You just need to specify them with length equal to length of the column.

```
  @name as varchar(100)
```